# Provide variations between desktop and mobile platforms

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

How can I add desktop-specific and mobile-specific objects and materials into a Unity 3D game?

Obviously I would not want the desktop resources to be compiled into the resulting iOS binary, and the same vice-versa.

Is there a best practice for achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined [a post](http://va.lent.in/blog/2011/12/13/so-how-do-teams-work-on-a-big-unity3d-project/) on how teams work with big unity3d projects. Check it out and watch videos to find out what best practices people use.

What you are asking was done in [Smuggle Truck](http://video.unity3d.com/video/3708116/unite-11-postmortem-smuggle) using their [Multiplatform Toolkit](http://smuggletruck.com/multiplatform/) which is available in Asset Store.